# Execution of xgraph to compute throughput and packet delay using NS2

Tags: networking, ns2

I have implemented Distance Vector protocol in NS2 and now i want to execute xgraph for throughput and packet delay. I know that i have to insert equations for throughput and delay as well as exec xgraph command, but i am unable to integrate this into my code. Could someone please help me out.

```
    set ns [new Simulator]  
set nr [open thro.tr w]
$ns trace-all $nr
set nf [open thro.nam w]

$ns namtrace-all $nf
        proc finish { } { // finish procedure   
        global ns nr nf
        $ns flush-trace
        close $nf
        close $nr
        exec nam thro.nam &
    exit 0
        }

for { set i 0 } { $i < 12} { incr i 1 } { // Number of nodes
set n($i) [$ns node]}

for {set i 0} {$i < 8} {incr i} {
$ns duplex-link $n($i) $n([expr $i+1]) 1Mb 10ms DropTail } // Link bandwidth and delay
$ns duplex-link $n(0) $n(8) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n(1) $n(10) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n(0) $n(9) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n(9) $n(11) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n(10) $n(11) 1Mb 10ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n(11) $n(5) 1Mb 10ms DropTail

set udp0 [new Agent/UDP] // Traffic UDP 
$ns attach-agent $n(0) $udp0
set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr0 set  interval_ 0.005
$cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
set null0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n(5) $null0
$ns connect $udp0 $null0

set udp1 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n(1) $udp1
set cbr1 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr1 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr1 set  interval_ 0.005
$cbr1 attach-agent $udp1
set null0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n(5) $null0
$ns connect $udp1 $null0

$ns rtproto DV // routing protocol used

$ns rtmodel-at 10.0 down $n(11) $n(5)
$ns rtmodel-at 15.0 down $n(7) $n(6)
$ns rtmodel-at 30.0 up $n(11) $n(5)
$ns rtmodel-at 20.0 up $n(7) $n(6)

$udp0 set fid_ 1
$udp1 set fid_ 2

$ns color 1 Green
$ns color 2 Blue

$ns at 1.0 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 2.0 "$cbr1 start"

$ns at 45 "finish"
$ns run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"VIII. Creating Output Files for Xgraph" http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript4.html

Xgraph examples : xgraph_ns2-files-tcl_09.17.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNczFLV0ZnNWdVY2s/view?usp=sharing → → the file n-code.tcl is a "DV example".

DV-examples-3.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRzBzOGdRODNwcVU/view?usp=sharing

- Instead of creating files for Xgraph, you can analyze the trace file
  with **APP-Tool**
- https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

Some APP-Tool results, "QasimCool-DV.tcl" https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfij7vhpo49t0r1/DV-QuasimCool.tar.gz?dl=0 → → Delay-figure_3.png, Thr-figure_1.png, 1-Instantaneous-throughput_thro.tr.txt, Instantaneous-delay_thro.tr.txt

[image]

About your file : " // " is not a valid "comment character" for an ns2 file.tcl . Lines 7, 16, 20, 28, 48 were edited :

```
7        proc finish { } {             ;# finish procedure

16 for { set i 0 } { $i < 12} { incr i 1 } {    ;# Number of nodes

20 $ns duplex-link $n($i) $n([expr $i+1]) 1Mb 10ms DropTail } ;# Link bandwidth and delay

28 set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]            ;# Traffic UDP

48 $ns rtproto DV                       ;# routing protocol used
```

Comment: Sir this is true, but isn't it possible to integrate throughput and delay within this code because i am using cygwin and unable to analyze this using app tool?

Comment: APP-Tool easy : Install 'VirtualBox' into Windows©, then install Ubuntu 16.04 into VirtualBox. ... And analyze your trace file(s) in Ubuntu / app-tool. Also easy : Use the awk files from app-tool to analyze  thro.tr ( No graph ).  ... ... The hard way : Learn how to write / code your file.tcl to create files for xgraph.